# Files in Downloads folder deleted automatically

Tags: 12.04, directory

As mentioned in the title, this has been happening for some days. And now that; whatever I download from Linux DC++, it goes to /home/user/Downloads folder (set as default in DC++ settings) but after some time it disapears on its own. I had around 40GB worth of data in my Downloads folder which got lost automatically.

The problem is that in properties it is showing 2GB of space remaining where it should have shown 42GB remaining. This means that the 40 GB space has become irrecoverable.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. - This has happened with me before. That time I found all my files in the /home/.dc++ folder. But this time I can't find them anywhere.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

`singhaal@singhaal-PC:~$ uname -a`

`Linux singhaal-PC 3.2.0-58-generic-pae #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 18:00:02 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @Kush : Thanx a ton. Disk Usage Analyzer solved my problem in a jiffy !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually DC++ downloads files in segments (from multiple sources, being a p2p network) and all those raw segments are first downloaded at some cache folder and then they're moved to your designated downloads folder when download is complete, so IMO, your 40 GB of space might've been consumed by that folder, try looking up in Disk Usage Analyzer.

Comment: I have one more question. Why does this happen though? I didn't understand the thing!!

Comment: @crisron Usually cache folder location can also be controlled in DC preferences, try altering that location by pointing it to same downloads folder, also are you using anything like Ubuntu Tweak (which periodically cleans up junk files)? Alternatively, if you have multiple partitions, set your downloads folder to different partition.

Comment: That download folder also had some files downloaded from the browser. They also got moved to /home/.dc++. I am not using Ubuntu Tweak or anything else to clean up junk files.

Answer (score 4):

Similar thing happened to me. LinuxDC++ crashed and all the files in the Downloads folder got deleted. But I found them in /home/.dc++/FileLists/ folder and restored them(The .dc++ folder is a hidden one and can be seen by enabling the "Show Hidden Folders" option in the top right-corner pulldown menu)

Hope this helps

Comment: Why does LinuxDC++ do this?

Comment: Not sure, what LinuxDC++ has to do with this, but the problem and this solution is true. My dc++ also crashed and I see all my items from the downloads folder in the mentioned path in this answer.